# Cytoscape and Java 11 installed, but will not read a table

Tags: cytoscape

I installed Cytoscape, Java 11, and ran the Windows Bat file. Everything seems ok. When trying to open a node table, I get many "couldn't find resource" errors:

```
The virtual key 'VK_?' does not exist.
couldn't find resource 'layout.grid.props' in jar.
adding IO taskFactory
couldn't find resource 'layout.force-directed.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.hierarchical.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.stacked-node-layout.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.attributes-layout.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.circular.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.isom.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.cose.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.kamada-kawai.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.fruchterman-rheingold.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.degree-circle.props' in jar.
couldn't find resource 'layout.attribute-circle.props' in jar.
```

Is there a way to connect to these resources?

Answer (score 0):

Those are "normal".  It means that you haven't used those layouts yet.  How are you trying to open the node table?

-- scooter